# Python icalendar ascii encoding issue

Tags: python

I am trying to run a script (I found [here](http://howto.pui.ch/post/37471158372/fetch-publicly-available-google-calendar-data-with)) that reads .ics files (which I got from google calendar). This is the code:

```
from icalendar import Calendar
import urllib
ics = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/calendarlink/basic.ics').read()
ical=Calendar.from_ical(ics)
for vevent in ical.subcomponents:
  if vevent.name != "VEVENT":
    continue
  title = str(vevent.get('SUMMARY'))
  description = str(vevent.get('DESCRIPTION'))
  location = str(vevent.get('LOCATION'))
  start = vevent.get('DTSTART').dt      # a datetime
  end = vevent.get('DTEND').dt        # a datetime
```

I get this error:

```
C:\python test>c:\Python27\python.exe google-calendar-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google-calendar-test.py", line 8, in <module>
    title = str(vevent.get('SUMMARY'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 47:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
The answer: I had to change line 8 to:

```
title = str(vevent.get('SUMMARY').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: Also, the google.com link provided is 404.

Comment: solved... just had to add .encode('utf-8')